# Unity 2D SetActive() is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

Here I used SetActive(true) to enable my gameObject but it is not working. I tried using various functions and objects that can enable my gameObj as can be seen in code. But nothing is working. Though when I set setActive(false), it works but that's not incase of setActive(true). I don't know the reason. Can anyone help me please? By the way I'm using Unity 4.3.4 version.

```
if (paddle.life == 1) {  
                GameObject life_2 = GameObject.Find ("life2");
                GameObject lost = GameObject.Find("lostlife");
                life_2.SetActive (false);
                lost.SetActive(true);
                //lost.active = true;
                //lost.renderer.enabled = true;(why null ref)

                //after some secs disable the message
                //Destroy(lost, 4);
            }
```

Comment: Define "not working" - what's actually happening?

Comment: try to debug your code. using breakpoints may be. it must be something wrong with your code logic.

Comment: Calling set active will only set the localActive flag to the value you give in the function.  If a parent game object is a deactivated none of the children will become active

Answer (score 1):

A part from [unity doc for GameObject.Find](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html):

> If no game object with name can be found, null is returned. If name
>   contains a '/' character it will traverse the hierarchy like a path
>   name. **This function only returns active gameobjects.**

Probably you need to reference your gameObject in the script as a parameter. This way you have reference to the gameObject (whether it is active or not) and it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

you have used:

```
lost.active = false;
```

and

```
lost.renderer.enabled = false;
```

but the main one is this:

```
lost.enabled = false;
```